# Python/Numpy - calculate sum of equal array elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum, unique

I have two numpy arrays, looking like:

```
field = np.array([5,1,3,3,2,1,6])    
counts = np.array([100,210,300,150,20,90,170])
```

They are not sorted (and shouldnt change). I now want to calculate a third array (of the same length and order) which contains the sum of the counts whenever they lie in the same field. Here the result should be:

```
field_counts = np.array([100,300,450,450,20,300,170])
```

The arrays are very long, such that iterating through it (and always looking where the corresponding partner fields are) is way too inefficient. Maybe I am just not seeing the wood for the trees... I hope someone can help me out on this!

Comment: Aside: when you find yourself needing a `groupby` operation, that's often a sign you should be using `pandas` instead of `numpy`; your operation would be something like `df.groupby("field")["counts"].transform(sum)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it will be efficient enough (since I do iterate over `field`) but here is a suggestion. I first make a directory of field/counts values. Then, I create an array based on that.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dic = defaultdict(int)
for j, f in enumerate(field):
    dic[f] += counts[j]

field_counts = np.array([dic[f] for f in field])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following list comprehension :

```
>>> [np.sum(counts[np.where(field==i)]) for i in field]
[100, 300, 450, 450, 20, 300, 170]
```

You can get the index of same elements in `field` with `np.where` :

```
>>> [np.where(field==i) for i in field]
[(array([0]),), (array([1, 5]),), (array([2, 3]),), (array([2, 3]),), (array([4]),), (array([1, 5]),), (array([6]),)]
```

And then get the corresponding elements of `counts` with indexing! and calculate the `sum` with `np.sum`.

Comment: This will be very slow if the arrays are long; you've made this an N^2 calculation.

Answer (score 1):

This problem an be solved in a fully vectorized manner using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author)

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
g = npi.group_by(field)
field_counts = g.sum(counts)[1][g.inverse]
```

g.sum computes the sums for each group of unique fields, and g.inverse maps those values back to the original fields.

Comment: There is a reason a went through the hassle to package this functionality, since there are indeed many questions of this type. In my perception, all these questions stand to benefit from my answers; as does this one. It substantially improves upon the currently accepted answer in several respects. It is my understanding that the sections you refer to are directed at commercial purposes; but this is a free-as-in-beer open-source package, but correct me if I'm wrong. My only selfish motive here is getting it better tested :).

Comment: Subjectively, it feels more like self-promotion to me if I do mention my authorship; but thank you for the heads-up. Do you happen to have a link to any resources that are a bit more explicit about the distinction between commercial and non-commercial purposes?

Comment: Some of them are duplicates I would say, yes. I will follow your suggestion to disclose authorship then, thanks.

Comment: I do appreciate the feedback

Comment: Awesome @EelcoHoogendoorn I see you added disclosure :). Please do the same for your other answers as well. As a side-note, if some of them are duplicates, feel free to flag them as such! I will delete my previous comments to clean up.